# Looping in Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programming so I don't know exactly what's OKAY and not okay in terms of performance.

I have a rails view where I want to loop through 4 arrays and within each of those arrays, I want to loop through 3 sub-sets.

Is this an okay sequence or too much going on for a view?

Comment: Please post some of your code

Comment: what's the size of your array? are they active record collection or just regular ruby array?

Comment: There is no problem doing that, just keep control on the size of your array and its subsets.

Comment: Views are to represnt your data - if you need to display the amount of those arrays then you have to loop over them. It is not whether you should loop over them, it is about `how` you do that. Especially fragile are loops over `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection as they can introdce extremely heavy N+1 issues. More code required to tell anything more.

Comment: @Coderhs they are ruby arrays of AR objects